# I have 3 rows in PHP table created with HTML each containing button with same name How can I fetch the data from the row where the button is clicked?

Tags: php, mysqli

i have three rows each row has a button with same name.i want to select data form database for that row only where the button is clicked.Thanks in advance

Comment: you should have a unique value, probably an ID and pass it to a javascript function which will do the ajax request to your php file which will query the data based from the ID. that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to have buttons with the same name?? just add an unique id in the name. 
Alternatively, you can put each row+button and a hidden input field with unique name and to check

```
if(isset($_Post["hiddenID"]))
```

I dont know why would you want to do it this way though.
Or did you want to know how to put the data from database into the row, instead of finding the correct row to put them??

Comment: The concept of my page is that it displays project details in with short description & in the same row i provide a button with name as "View details" . This page will redirect the user to another page where it shows the description from the row where button is clicked.

Comment: This is about hirer and freelancer.Hirer post details which are shown in the page but they are short description so i provide them button, i can not add unique id to every button as there can be many, any idea how to auto increment buttons and then fetch their generated id?? I am new to php. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. you need do auto increment buttons.
u can use something like this.
<?php $id=0; ?>



input type="button" name=<?php echo "\"button".$id."\">"; $id++ ?>

Comment: the button names should be button0, button1, button2 and so on.